# Remap menu key to delta (Δ)?

Tags: xubuntu, keyboard, remapping, xbindkeys, xte

I'm using Xubuntu 14.04. My keyboard is a Belgian AZERTY. I never use my menu key, and I use the delta sign a lot. I'm not willing to switch keyboard layouts to Greek, as the delta is the only thing I use. I've tried:

- Xmodmap, but that didn't work as it isn't compatible anymore, someone told me.
- A combination of Xbindkeys and Xte

I've put this in my .xbindkeysrc file:

```
"xte 'keydown Control_L' 'keydown Shift_L' 'key u' 'key agrave' 'key quotedbl' 'key ccedilla' 'key apostrophe' 'keyup Control_L' 'keyup Shift_L'"
Menu
```

This didn't do anything, even after restarting, except that I can't use the menu key anymore (I intended to do that, but it had to type a delta too.)

- Adding the Xte command above as a keyboard shortcut. Didn't work, again, except stopping the menu key from doing its normal job. **Note: the command does type a delta for me if I enter it in the terminal, it's just not working as a keyboard shortcut.**

Any other ways to do this, or things I am do wrong? And how can I do this with Xkb, because I have no clue and it seems to be Xmodmap's replacement?

Comment: Why the menu key? If you want to add it to the keyboard layout (for example with AltGr) I can help.

Comment: Well, because I never use the menu key. Adding it to the keyboard key would be good too, if that's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I saw the Belgian AZERTY keyboard. It has four full levels, so I tried to find a way to define DELTA on the menu key. It’s easy. Let’s do this in steps:

1. Open the layout file for editing. To do this you can open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter the command:

   `sudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/be`
2. Define DELTA for the MENU key. Just insert the following line somewhere in the block "basic", for example in line 42 just before `include "level3(ralt_switch)"`:

   ```
   key <MENU>  { [Greek_DELTA ] };
   ```

   Then, save and close the file.
3. Return to the terminal and run the command `sudo dpkg-reconfigure xkb-data`.
4. Just log out, or if you have more than one layout just change the layout once.

Now you can insert “Δ” with MENU.